# Exporting partial table records as INSERT script

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have datatable with a large amount of data in it and I'm trying to export the data from it. I saved the file locally, but I cannot open it with Notepad++. The problem is that I just want to get some of the data as an INSERT script but I don't know if this is possible.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to get some of the data from a table as an INSERT script using SQL Server 2014?

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you want (taken from [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36986758) answer by [KT.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318964/kt):

> - Do a `select [whatever you need]`**`INTO temp.table_name`**`from [... etc ...]`.
>
>   - Right-click on the database in the Object Explorer => Tasks => Generate Scripts
>   - Select `temp.table_name` in the "Choose Objects" screen, click Next.
>   - In the "Specify how scripts should be saved" screen:
>   - Click Advanced, find the "Types of data to Script" property, select "Data only", close the advanced properties.
>   - Select "Save to new query window" (unless you have thousands of records).
>   - Click Next, wait for the job to complete, observe the resulting `INSERT` statements appear in a new query window.
>   - Use Find & Replace to change all `[temp.table_name]` to `[your_table_name]`.
>   - `drop table [temp.table_name]`.

NOTE:  The above sample uses the schema name `temp`. You may have to create that schema name for the script to work for you.